# oactve: modify each element according to a simple condition

Tags: octave

New to octave here.

I have a matrix X, would like to change all the element (as a numeric number) like this:  if the value of the element is greater than 10, change it to 10, otherwise, keep the same value.

In theory I can do a two loops and go through each element. Wonder if there is a simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I looks like the idiomatic way to do that is using [logical indexing](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/Logical-Values.html):

```
A(A>10)=10
```

---

Use [Function Application (`@arrayfun`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Function-Application.html):

```
> A=[10, 20, 30; 9, 13, 8]
> arrayfun (@(x) ifelse (x>10, 10, x), A)
ans =

   10   10   10
    9   10    8
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be done very simply, and more efficiently, with [logical indexing](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/Logical-Values.html):

```
A(A>10) = 10;
```

Another option is to use the [`min`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/min.html) function:

```
A = min(A,10);
```

Comment: This is the most efficient way